# Developing for Multiple Platforms

Tags: java, android, windows, cross-platform, porting

I have a partially developed Java game which runs fine on my Windows PC. I want to maintain the PC version, but also start porting it to Android. For the mostpart, the classes handling the calculations and gameplay are separate from the GUI functions already.

I'm using Eclipse, so should I keep both versions in the same project, for example? I'm hoping that my gameplay classes and methods don't have to be modified and that all I need to do is add an activity for my Android device which will include its display / user input functionality. Do I need to create a new project and copy my methods?

Is there a standard process for any of this?

Comment: [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) sounds perfect for you, if it's not already too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use your current code, by creating a library and importing it into your Android project. To this you can either

A. Cut and paste the current class into the Android code. This makes maintenance a little harder.

B. Add the library by right clicking on the project in Eclipse and go to Build Path > Configure build path. In there you will find a Libraries tab. Click it and select "Add new". The rest should be pretty intuitive.

I'd opt for the second option, and it is easier to maintain and implement into the new project.

Comment: How do I "take classes and add them to android"? Do you mean cut and paste like the other respondent? It just seems counter-intuitive to the purpose of libraries.

Comment: You can A. Cut and paste; or, B. At the library by right clicking on the project and go to Build Path > Configure build path. In there you will find a Libraries tab. Click it and select "Add new". The rest should be pretty intiuitive.

Comment: TBH, I think you should submit the above as an answer. I would accept the answer that I should create a new project, but add the existing classes as a library using the idiot's guide to the configuration path!! Many thanks!

Comment: There's no package declaration for the class. How do I import it, please?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking.

Comment: Me too. Just learning the terminology. So, in my Android project, I've referenced the directory containing the generic Java. Eclipse has called that a referenced library. Now I want to use one of the classes in my new project. When I call one of the methods, the new project doesn't seem to "know" about them. I tried "import" and the name of the class, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want to use a method 1. you need to import the file 2. create an object, unless the method is static

Comment: Stuck on this. I've added the class folder in the Libraries tab of the Build Path configuration, but I still can't call the method. If I attempt to "import" the containing class, the import doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommending a different project. This way you keep the overhead for each project clean. It wouldn't be much of a hassle to copy paste any changes in the COMMON classes (library classes) used on each project.  At the end you benefit of a cleaner work environment with 2 projects.

Comment: No, not much hassle but it seems to defeat the purpose of "library" classes. What's the point in having a library class you can't re-use?

Comment: I meant library classes. Most of the time you have library classes copied in each project root library folder though. That's why i said you have to update them both when adding changes (updating library).unless you import it from outside your project folder in your build path.